# Export functions Nodejs

Tags: node.js

I'm using module.exports to export list of module. Below is my 
Models/Message.js

```
var msgModel = function()
{
    var getMsg = function() {
        return "Hello World";
    }
    return{
        getMsg : getMsg
    }
}
module.exports =  msgModel;
```

Below is my app.js

```
var msgModel = require('./Models/Message');
console.log(msgModel.getMsg());
```

It raised me error

```
console.log(msgModel.getMsg());
                 ^
```

I can't figure out the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to do `console.log(msgModel().getMsg());`. This is because msgModel is a function. I would suggest rewriting your msgModel like the example below instead to achieve the call you wanted.

```
var msgModel = {
    getMsg: function() {
        return "Hello World";
    }
};

module.exports = msgModel;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
var msg = new msgModel();
console.log(msg.getMsg());
```

Answer (score 2):

You should export a function and invoke it in the main app.js

***for example:***

***app.js***

```
var msgModel = require('./Models/Message');
msgModel();
```

***Message.js***

```
var getMsg = function(){
    console.log("Hello World!");
};

module.exports = getMsg;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write it this way in order to group more functions:

```
module.exports =  {
    getMsg: function() {
        return "Hello World";
    },
    anotherFnc: function () {
     ...
    }
};
```

then you could use:

```
var msgModel = require('./Models/Message');
console.log(msgModel.getMsg());
```